# OMSDroid.MapView NoClassDefFound while using OSMDroid in Android Studio Project

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, osmdroid

I am trying to set up a new Android application that uses the OSMDroid apis to handle mapping.  I followed the tutorial that seems to be the most common online and after getting through the majority of the errors I have gotten stuck. The application will compile but as soon as it starts I get a runtime error that says NoClassDefFound for org.osmdroid.MapView.  As per all of the other Stack Overflow suggestions I have made sure that the jars are all in the folder libs in the project directory.  I am using Android Studio so that adds to the complication.  For reference here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar')
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/osmdroid-android-3.0.10.jar')
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/osmdroid-third-party-3.0.10.jar')
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/osmdroid-packager-3.0.10.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 14
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is to download the Jar file from OSMDroid repo https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/Downloads

then your gradle should look like this in the dependecies section:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('.../libraries/osmdroid-android-4.2.jar')
    compile files('.../libraries/slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1.jar')
}
```

Or just follow this link:

https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/HowToIncludeInYourProject